# Flutter: How to reuse same page but with different bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have a page, which is used to display some multi-media in grid view.
In this page, I can upload photos/videos.

My app has a group data structure, and in a group, there is a list of posts.

Group can have multi-media attached, and also, post can have multi-media attached.

So the multi-media grid view page can be opened from group, or from a post.

So my idea is, I will re-use the view page, but with different bloc.

For Group multi-media one, will use a `GroupBloc`, and for post, will use a `PostBloc`

So my question is, How do I re-use the same page widget (the multi-media grid view) but inject different Bloc so that inside the widget it calls the right bloc to add event, and rebuild the widget with the right bloc state?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can create combine bloc with 2 different bloc like this

```
class BlocCombineBloc extends Bloc<BlocCombineEvent, BlocCombineState> {
  final BlocABloc blocA;
  final BlocBBloc blocB;

  BlocCombineBloc(this.blocA, this.blocB);

  @override
  BlocCombineState get initialState => InitialBlocCombineState();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I still don't quite get how to use it to solve my problem. It would be great if you can explain it more or provide some example to use combine bloc. Thanks!

Comment: Make 2 blocs with different events and states and then combine those 2 bloc inside one single bloc, and then use particular event and states